# Finding specific item in class-list in Python

Tags: python, list

Im working on a project where I created a class named Image.

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.pixelArray = None
    self.key = None

def setPixelArray(self, pixelArray):
    self.pixelArray = pixelArray

def setKey(self, key):
    self.key = key
```

Later on i create a list containing Images. And now I want to in a easy way get a specific item out of that list using the name attribute, `image.name`. Below you can see me getting the imageid that i want to find in the already created image-list.

```
split = line.split()

imageid = split[0]
key = split[1]
```

I have been looking around but not found any example of how to do this without a lot of loops. Is there an easy way to rewrite

```
if x in myList:
    do something with x:
```

Comment: Please post a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - but chances are that what you want is a dict.

Comment: Also (totally unrelated but) your `setPixelArray` and `setKey` methods are totally useless - just set the attributes directly and you're done. If you later need to control access to those attributes you can always turn them into computed attributes using `property`.

Comment: There is no general way to use a list to do this without looping. Instead use a `dict` and map names to your objects.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm new to Python and did not know of dict. Wanted it to be lika struct in C and i think this will make it work!